# How can I resize web pages that detect my monitor size instead of the browser size?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When it comes to large texts I prefer to read them in narrow columns. A trick that works often is hitting:

<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

to resize the browser to half screen. [A certain website](http://www.atheistalliance.org/news-a-articles/presidents-corner/371--you-have-to-like-lots-of-things-to-fight-against-one-big-dislike) however isn't resizing accordingly; I guess it's doing some size detection because my screen is rather large and occupies quite a bit of its width, but it is detecting the whole screen size instead of the browser size.

How can I make such malformed sites behave well when I can't fix them? Are there any tricks? I tried reloading but it didn't work. I use Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: Try disabling JavaScript.

Comment: @Gareth Thanks for the edit. ESL users like me need you.

Comment: @Hello71 I downloaded Javascript blacklist for Chrome and it didn't work. I will try another way and then I will report the results.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that page, and many others, don't resize properly is that they used a fixed width for certain elements in the page.

When you do <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> on your provided [website](http://www.atheistalliance.org/news-a-articles/presidents-corner/371--you-have-to-like-lots-of-things-to-fight-against-one-big-dislike), notice when you scroll to the right where it ends?  It stops at the end of the menu bar.  Looking at the source of the page, the menu bar has a fixed width of 960 pixels, thereby making it the minimum width of the page.  If they removed the menu bar, the page would resize to any width, as there are no other fixed widths in the source.

Comment: how *do* you do the buttons?

Comment: Actually it's the CSS on class `wrapper` that is fixing the width at 960px (check the main page source). For a once-off, you can make the page content not be fixed width by using Chrome's developer tools. `Ctrl+Shift+I` to show dev tools, `Elements` tab, find the `div` with class `wrapper`, and untick the `width` rule in the table on the right.

Comment: meh, I just glanced at the source looking for width.  I didnt take a good look at it.  :)

Comment: @Keltari `<kbd>Key</kbd>`

Comment: I wish it was 960px wide. In my screen the text alone it's 1300px wide